# Nagios - Is it possible to force check of all hosts by using a command in any given moment?

Tags: centos, nagios

I've fixed many issues on servers which indicated errors on Nagios but for some reason the alert is still up even though the problem has been fixed.
So i was wondering, is there a way to force check all hosts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way by far is to simply restart Nagios. Upon a restart it will begin a new checking cycle.

Comment: for some reason it doesn't, i used service nagios reload/restart and the servers which indicated a problem and have been fixed still appear on the Nagios and still indicating on a problem.

Comment: Then I think you may have another problem altogether. e.g. The checks on the monitored servers may not be functioning correctly or just not returning the correct data.

Comment: The alert it indicated about was correct, when i logged into the problematic server i saw the problem exacly how it was indicated on Nagios but after fixing it, the alert doesn't disappear.

Comment: Try executing the check manually from the nagios server.

Answer (score 2):

> So i was wondering, is there a way to force check all hosts?

[`SCHEDULE_FORCED_HOST_SVC_CHECKS`](http://old.nagios.org/developerinfo/externalcommands/commandinfo.php?command_id=30) external command is what you're looking for.

To get all of your hosts, take a look at the [MK Livestatus](http://mathias-kettner.de/checkmk_livestatus.html):

```
# echo -e 'GET hosts\nColumns: host_name' | unixcat /usr/local/nagios/var/rw/live
```

then pipe to the `SCHEDULE_FORCED_HOST_SVC_CHECKS` command:

`echo -e 'GET hosts\nColumns: host_name' | unixcat /usr/local/nagios/var/rw/live | while read host; do echo "[$(date +%s)] SCHEDULE_FORCED_HOST_SVC_CHECKS;$host;$(date +%s)\n" $(date +%s) >> /usr/local/nagios/var/rw/nagios.cmd; done`

Comment: great, does thich check all the services on each host as well? or just host connectivity?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bash script based on Nagios' sample script and the external command "SCHEDULE_FORCED_HOST_SVC_CHECKS":

```
#!/bin/sh
# This is a sample shell script showing how you can submit the SCHEDULE_HOST_SVC_CHECKS command
# to Nagios. Adjust variables to fit your environment as necessary.

now=`date +%s` commandfile='/usr/local/nagios/var/rw/nagios.cmd'

for i in hosts/*.cfg
        do
                SITE=$(grep host_name $i | head -1 | sed 's/host_name//' | tr -d '[:blank:]')
                /usr/bin/printf "[%lu] SCHEDULE_HOST_SVC_CHECKS;${SITE};1110741500\n" $now > $commandfile
        done
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/joshforcier/nagiosForceImmediateCheck

Here is a Nagios XI component to force an immediate check on multiple hosts/services.